# how to create laravel dynamic single row value

Tags: php, laravel

i am trying to create single row dynamic drop-down. give me reference or give me example.

my table
[image]

I NEED THIS ANSWER IN DROP DOWN

[image]

[image]

Comment: We are more than happy to provide help but you need to have shown that you have attempted to solve the problem yourself. Please update your question with what you have tried so far.

Comment: @Spholt i am not yet started to code this but i have so many confusion on it , please give reference or give demo for this thank you

Comment: It's recommended that you attempt making this, show us what you tried, why it didn't work and then we can suggest potential solutions.

Comment: @Tomas Crofty  if you give reference it will help me to develop, i am not asking ready answer, just i am asking share your knowledge. thank you

Comment: The issue is that you've been extremely vague in your question so it's even harder to suggest a solution

Answer (score 0):

if I understand your question then I think this can ve the correct answer

```
public function data(){
$datas = Model::all();
return view('your view name',compact('datas'));
}

in your blade

<form action="{{url('YourUrlforFormSubmit')}}">
    <select name="product">
    foreach($datas as $data)
    <option value="{{$data->id}}">{{$data->name}}</option>
    </select>
</form>
```

in web.php

```
Route::post('YourUrlforFormSubmit','YourController@saveData')
```

in controller

```
public function saveData(Request $request){
    $data = Model::find($request->id);

    $save = new YournewModel; //whereyou want to save the data
    $save->part_id = $data->part_id;
    $save->name= $data->name;
    $save->price= $data->price;
    $save->save();
    return view('your view name',compact('datas'));
    }
```

Comment: {{$data->name}} this value for right for collecting NAME, after  i what to show automatically fill column PART-ID and also PRICE

Comment: thank you, before i save data i want to show this data in view

Comment: can you help me to get data in view before save